# Содержит ли массив все числа в промежутке

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю как решить задачу. Допустим есть двумерный массв из целых чисел

> [
> [ 7, 4, 3, 2, 6 ],
> [ 6, 2, 8, 9, 6 ],
> [ 9, 7, 1, 1, 4 ], ]

Мне нужно определить содержит ли каждый участок 3*3 все числа от 1 до 9

Не пойму как проверять такими участками во всех массивах вместе. И как проверять наличие именно всех чисел в промежутке от 1 до 9

Comment: В массивах могут быть только числа от 1 до 9?

Comment: В матрице могут быть только три строки?

Comment: Числа только от 1 до 9, а количество строк сколько хочешь.

Answer (score 2):

А в чем проблема -

1. двигаетесь в двумерном цикле с окном 3x3
2. все числа из окна 3 x 3 заносите в Set()
3. сравниваете множество с эталонным

Решение в лоб:

код:

```
// двигаемся по матрице m x n
for (i = 0; i < n - 3; i ++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m - 3; j++) {

        digits = new Set();

        // собираем все числа в окне 3 x 3
        for (x = 0; x < 3; x ++) {
            for (y = 0; y < 3; y ++) {
                digits.add(arr[i + x][j + y]);
            }
        }

         // сравниваем множество с {1,2,3...}
    }
}
```

Тут куча места для оптимизаций есть, но для понимания пока лучше решать в лоб

Comment: Если в матрице могут быть только числа от 1 до 9, можно просто проверить `digits.size === 9`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, конечно - но это уже заточки и оптимизашки